# How to work with Android 1 DataBase 2 tables inside

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello a week ago i didn't know much about Android Database
nowadays i understand much at table TABLE_GOODS all is OK 
created my DB and all is working perfect now saving at DB and even i can see at ListView all DB. That's good but now i am faced with other problem.
i have to create second table TABLE_SELL at this DB.
what i am doing?
at Prihod activity i am saving goods which come to my shop at TABLE_GOODS.
at Rashod activity now i have to save what i sell at TABLE_SELL. 
i am using class Goods to write

```
public class Goods {
private int id;
private String name_goods;
private String date;
private String amount;
private String cost;

public Goods() {
}

public Goods(int id, String name_goods, String date, String amount, String cost) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name_goods = name_goods;
    this.date = date;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.cost = cost;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName_goods() {
    return name_goods;
}

public void setName_goods(String name_goods) {
    this.name_goods = name_goods;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(String cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Goods[id: " + id + ", name_goods: " + name_goods + ", date: " + date + ", "   +
            "amount: " + amount + ", cost: " + cost + "]";
}
```

here i am working with DataBase

```
public class DBHandlerImpl extends SQLiteOpenHelper  implements DBHandler<Goods>    {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "app_bases";

private static final String TABLE_GOODS = "users";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME_GOODS = "name_goods";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
private static final String KEY_COST = "cost";

private static final String TABLE_SELL = "sell";
private static final String KEY_ID_RASHOD = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME_GOODS_RASHOD = "name_goods";
private static final String KEY_DATE_RASHOD = "date";
private static final String KEY_AMOUNT_RASHOD = "amount";
private static final String KEY_COST_RASHOD = "cost";

public DBHandlerImpl(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "Create Table " + TABLE_GOODS + "(" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                                                        KEY_NAME_GOODS + " TEXT, " +
                                                        KEY_DATE + " TEXT, " +
                                                        KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT, " +
                                                        KEY_COST + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(query);

    String queryLose = "Create Table " + TABLE_SELL + "(" + KEY_ID_RASHOD + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                                                        KEY_NAME_GOODS_RASHOD + " TEXT, " +
                                                        KEY_DATE_RASHOD + " TEXT, " +
                                                        KEY_AMOUNT_RASHOD + " TEXT, " +
                                                        KEY_COST_RASHOD + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(queryLose);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void add(Goods goods) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME_GOODS, goods.getName_goods());
    values.put(KEY_DATE, goods.getDate());
    values.put(KEY_AMOUNT, goods.getAmount());
    values.put(KEY_COST, goods.getCost());
    db.insert(TABLE_GOODS, null, values);

    values.put(KEY_NAME_GOODS_RASHOD, goods.getName_goods());
    values.put(KEY_DATE_RASHOD, goods.getDate());
    values.put(KEY_AMOUNT_RASHOD, goods.getAmount());
    values.put(KEY_COST_RASHOD, goods.getCost());
    db.insert(TABLE_SELL, null, values);
    db.close();
  }
```

Here I'm working with PrihodActivity where I save TABLE_GOODS

```
public class Prihod  extends Activity{
private DBHandler<Goods> db;
private Goods goods;
private EditText edtTovar;
private EditText editDate;
private EditText editAmount;
private EditText editCost;
private Button btn_save;
private Button btn_info;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.prihod);
    TextView textTovar = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTovar);
    TextView textDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    TextView textAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAmount);
    TextView textCost = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCost);
    edtTovar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTovar);
    editDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDate);
    editAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAmount);
    editCost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCost);
    btn_save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btn_info = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_info);
    db = new DBHandlerImpl(this);

}

public void saveTovar(View v){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Prihod.this);
    builder.setTitle("Потдвердить сохранение...");
    builder.setMessage("Вы уверены, что хотите сохранить?");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.save);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            goods = new Goods(1, edtTovar.getText().toString(),
                    editDate.getText().toString(),
                    editAmount.getText().toString(),
                    editCost.getText().toString());
            db.add(goods);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Новый товар сохранен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}`
```

Comment: it was so difficult to write question really now question and words are all smashed please brothers answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing like first table. I saw you already created the second table. Just forgot to add something inside onUpgrade method: something like:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i2) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_GOODS );
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_SELL );
   onCreate(db);
}
```

A small [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). Just check for more.

And other things like insert, update, delete operations every logic are same. Just create methods are do whatever operation you want.

**EDIT**
Create your database class like :

```
public class DBHandlerImpl     {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "app_bases";
private static final String TABLE_GOODS = "users";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME_GOODS = "name_goods";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
private static final String KEY_COST = "cost";

private static final String TABLE_SELL = "sell";
private static final String KEY_ID_RASHOD = "_id";
private static final String KEY_NAME_GOODS_RASHOD = "_name_goods";
private static final String KEY_DATE_RASHOD = "_date";
private static final String KEY_AMOUNT_RASHOD = "_amount";
private static final String KEY_COST_RASHOD = "_cost";


private DbHelper mHelper;
private final Context mContext;
private SQLiteDataBase mDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public DBHandlerImpl(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String query = "Create Table " + TABLE_GOODS + "(" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                                                    KEY_NAME_GOODS + " TEXT, " +
                                                    KEY_DATE + " TEXT, " +
                                                    KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT, " +
                                                    KEY_COST + " TEXT);";
db.execSQL(query);

String queryLose = "Create Table " + TABLE_SELL + "(" + KEY_ID_RASHOD + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                                                    KEY_NAME_GOODS_RASHOD + " TEXT, " +
                                                    KEY_DATE_RASHOD + " TEXT, " +
                                                    KEY_AMOUNT_RASHOD + " TEXT, " +
                                                    KEY_COST_RASHOD + " TEXT);";
db.execSQL(queryLose);
}

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i2) {
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_GOODS );
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_SELL );
   onCreate(db);
 }
}

public DBHandlerImpl (Context c){
mContext = c;
}

public DBHandlerImpl open(){
mHelper = new DbHelper(mContext);
mDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){
mHelper.close();
}

public void add(Goods goods) {
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_NAME_GOODS, goods.getName_goods());
values.put(KEY_DATE, goods.getDate());
values.put(KEY_AMOUNT, goods.getAmount());
values.put(KEY_COST, goods.getCost());
mDatabase.insert(TABLE_GOODS, null, values);    
 }      

public void add_table_SellData(Goods goods ) {
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(KEY_NAME_GOODS_RASHOD, goods.getName_goods());
cv.put(KEY_DATE_RASHOD, goods.getDate());
cv.put(KEY_AMOUNT_RASHOD, goods.getAmount());
cv.put(KEY_COST_RASHOD, goods.getCost());
mDatabase.insert(TABLE_SELL, null, cv);
}
}
```

I have written all the programs roughly to make you understand. So please ignore the name errors.

In your activity 1st open the database, then insert data and then close the database.something like:

```
  DBHandlerImpl db = new DBHandlerImpl(current_context);
  db.open();
  db.add_table_SellData(your_data);
  db.close();
```

**2nd Edit**

```
public void saveTovar(View v){
//First Define AlertDialog here
AlertDialog alert;
//Ok now define the builder and initialize it through current context
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Prihod.this);
builder.setTitle("Потдвердить сохранение...");
builder.setMessage("Вы уверены, что хотите сохранить?");
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.save);
builder.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        goods = new Goods(1, edtTovar.getText().toString(),
                editDate.getText().toString(),
                editAmount.getText().toString(),
                editCost.getText().toString());

        //Create and initialize the database object here and delete it from oncreate() which already you define
        DBHandlerImpl db = new DBHandlerImpl(Prihod.this);
        //now open the database 
        db.open();
        now insert your data through corresponding methods
        db.add(goods);
        db.add_table_SellData(goods);
        //Now close it
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Новый товар сохранен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

builder.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
//Now initialize the alertdialog through create method of builder
alert = builder.create(); 
//Now show the alertdialog not the  builder   
alert.show();
}
```

Comment: brother i try what you say table TABLE_GOODS  has no problem at saving but second table TABLE_SELL again not saving and giving error and another question i cant put here error logs too long by 565 characters   is written below please guide me how to put add comment error code logs thanks

Comment: ok see my edited code. i dont have any knowledge about your interface which you implemented in database class.so i delete this and write the methods in a general way. you can use your interface with the new add_shellData method. thanks

Comment: thanks brother let me test and tell you results and how to put here error logs please can you tell me

Comment: copy logs from logcat and paste it with "{}" symbol which will show "enter code here option" and paste. If you have any..

Comment: Brother if i want to put error logs here with {} symbol too long by 1631 characters message below and i cant put logs please how ot solve i know maybe i border you but as newbie i have to ask someone thanks

Comment: copy and paste only 10 sentences from your errors which are in red from your logcat.

Comment: error only when i press save button 02-02 14:58:45.428    4542-4542/uz.akrampulatov.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at uz.akrampulatov.app.activity.Rashod$1.onClick(Rashod.java:59)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: hey, you have null pointer exception. which means there is some problem in your arguments.

Comment: o.o..there are many problems in your code.you are showing a builder where we have to show the alertdialog.ok.i will try to rectify your code and update here.

Comment: thanks to you very much i don't know how it happened but now i can save to second table and there is no error Thanks for your patience and good answers